# Trading View Pinescript v5 : Hline not plotting inside indicator

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

Hline not plotting inside indicator.

All conditions are met.

What is simple float?
How do i solve the issue

```
//@version=5

indicator(title='RSI_RS horizontal', shorttitle='RSI_RS horizontal', overlay=false, format=format.price)

rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

//RSI PLOT
plot(rsi, title='RSI', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=color.new(color.black, 0))


//====================================================================================
//HORIZONTAL MOVING LINES

//shortma = input(3, minval=2,type=input.integer, title="RSI MINI LENGTH")

horizontal = input.string(title='HORIZONTAL MOVING LINES TYPE', defval='60/40', options=['60/40', '80/40', '60/20', '80/20'])

var float top_h_line = 0.0
var float bottom_h_line = 0.0

if horizontal == '60/40'
    top_h_line := 60
    bottom_h_line := 40
else
    if horizontal == '80/40'
        top_h_line := 80
        bottom_h_line := 40
    else
        if horizontal == '80/20'
            top_h_line := 60
            bottom_h_line := 20
        else
            top_h_line := 80
            bottom_h_line := 20


hline(top_h_line)

//====================================================================================
```

ERROR:
**line 45: Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='top_h_line'. An argument of 'simple float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected**

Answer (score 0):

It means that it’s value must be known at compile time.

You can use the [lines](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/concepts/Lines_and_boxes.html#lines) instead.